# std::string::find returns different value for dereferenced iterator and equivalent string literal

Tags: c++

Here is a block of my code:

```
for (auto it = name.begin(); it != name.end(); it++) {
    cout << "\n" << "Fetching " << *it;
    cout << int(buf.find("cse3")) << "\n";
    cout << int(buf.find(*it)) << "\n";
    if (buf.find(*it) == string::npos) {
        cout << "No description for " << *it;
        cout << "In " << buf;
    } else if ...
...
}
```

where

```
vector<string> name = ...; 
string buf = ...;
```

And here is the output I got

```
Fetching cse3
0
-1
No description for cse3
In cse3" name="cse3"
```

I tried to look up the type, `*it` gives a `basic_string<char>` which is just string, `cse3` is a `A5_c`, which based on my research means `const array` of 5. However, why is `buf.find()` able to find a char array while cannot find a string?

Besides, I also found that `*it == cse3` actually returns 0. I think the overloaded `== operator` for string is able to compare string and string literal.

Why using an iterator and dereferencing it gives a weird behaving string?

Comment: @DimChtz: Since `name` is of type `vector<string>`, `*it` should return a `string`. @qileng: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I tested your code and it works as expected. Same result for string literal and dereferenced iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see there is a newline after `Fetching cse3`, which isn't in your code. That means that the string in the vector is actually `cse3\n`, so it's not being found.

There's nothing wrong with the `basic_string::find`, here's a demo:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> vec = { "abc", "abc\n" };
    string s = "abcdef";
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
        cout << static_cast<int>(s.find(*it)) << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
-1
```

Comment: please dont use/encourage c style casts `(int)s.find(..)` ... `static_cast` instead

Comment: what is the purpose of that cast?

Comment: @M.M I guess -1 is more recognisable (to some people) than the numeric value of `std::string::npos`

Comment: Without the cast the data type is unsigned, so `-1` looks different.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the problem. I noticed the `\n` but didn't realize that would naturally break the find.